# Calculating voltage output from a circuit with capacitors

Tags: voltage, capacitor, output, homework, circuits

The question is outlined in the image below. I am having trouble solving this problem. If at all possible would one of you please provide the solution. Thank you

[image]

Comment: This will involve conservation of energy.  Think in terms of 1/2CV^2.

Comment: I have added the homework tag. Please be aware that this site is not a homework solution source. Folks are here to help you get over the humps and through the ruts that you may find when you can show what work you have done and can explain where you are stuck. So please at least try to get on board with this and not outright ask for a problem solution.

Comment: No, this will involve the conservation of charge @relayman357

Comment: @relayman357, that's usually not the approach expected. Start with conservation of charge instead, and you'll get a different answer. This is a somewhat famous "paradoxical" circuit where both energy and charge can't be conserved. The usual explanation is that we have to consider resistive loss in the wires (no matter how small) to get a consistent answer (and thus energy is not conserved).

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka and Photon..

Comment: One way to think of it is that each time C2 is connected, the voltage *difference* will be reduced by 4/5 (C2/C1+C2) as 4/5 of the charge difference flows into C2 to equalize the voltage.

Comment: @MichaelKaras what answer does the textbook give?  If none, after homework is graded i'd like to hear what answer was given.

Comment: Reminds me the capacitor paradox.

Comment: Yes @RohatKılıç , I just found [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_capacitor_paradox) and it is helpful to think this through.

Comment: I attempted to solve the question under the assumption that charge is conserved at position B. I calculated the charge for t=0, t=4, t=8, and use the subsequent value to find the voltage at t=10 which should be the same as t=11 and found the value to be 12.2V. Did you guys manage to find a similar or the same result?

Answer (score 0):

This circuit can not be analyzed using normal circuit analysis techniques. It violates our **definition** of an ideal capacitor or of parallel elements.

Our definition of an ideal capacitor is that \$ i = C dv/dt\$. This implies
that the voltage across a capacitor can not change instantaneously, because doing so would require infinite current. Allowing infinite current blows up any mathematical analysis. So, at the instant when the switch moves to position B we know that the voltages across the capacitors will be the same as it was when the switch was in position A.

At the instant when you move the switch to position B, if the capacitors do not have the same voltage on them then you have two elements in parallel with different voltages, which violates our definition of "parallel" and also violates KVL.

As @ThePhoton has commented, you must have a resistive element between the capacitors to allow meaningful analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I think just use the charge conservation (V = applied Voltage):
$$Q_1 = C_1V$$
For \$2\le t \lt 4\$
$$Q = Q_1+Q_2 = C_1V + 0 = (C_1+C_2)V_2 \implies V_2 = \frac{C_1V}{C_1+C_2}$$
For \$6\le t <8\$
$$Q = Q_1+Q_2 = C_1V+ \frac{C_1C_2V}{C_1+C_2} = (C_1+C_2)V_2 \implies V_2 = \frac{C_1V}{C_1+C_2}+\frac{C_1C_2V}{(C_1+C_2)^2}$$
For \$t \ge 8,\$
$$V_2 = \frac{C_1V}{C_1+C_2}+\frac{C_1C_2V}{(C_1+C_2)^2}$$
Put in the values to get the result.